# Facebook auth plugin for play framework 2

Tags: facebook, authentication, playframework-2.0

is there any new Facebook authentication plugin for play framework 2(java)? İ can't find any. everything i found is for play 1.x version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure Social has out of the box support for facebook: http://securesocial.ws/guide/getting-started.html. It's written in scala but supports scala or java based play apps.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [play-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j) which supports OAuth (**Facebook**, Twitter, Google, Yahoo, LinkedIn, ...), CAS, SAML, OpenID (Connect) and GAE. See the demos: [play-pac4j-java-demo](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo) & https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo

Comment: pac4j doesn't have any meaningful documentation, so is useless